# Hide extension as well as replace Question mark by slash in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem i.e suppose the url is www.example.com/view.php?id=1 but I want the url is like that www.example.com/view/id/1 , seperately I get htaccess for hide extension or replace '?' by slash but both are not working please anybody help me .I want .htaccess working for both(extension hide and replace slash) and please make it general that is htaccess working for any page not any particular page.thanks in advance

Comment: There are uncounted solutions documented for this on this site or to be found on google. Any special reason why none of those solves your problem?

Comment: Also _ please_ post your current attempts. Otherwise we cannot sport the problem you face.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /view.php?id=1 to /view/id/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

# internal forward from /view/id/1 to /view.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: AnubHava, this is the best trouble free, copy-paste, no further questions asked solution I've seen for this particular subject.
Thank You for sharing such elegant, functional and simple solution.